# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider - for System group app (system/priv-app/)

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

I have my application installed along with the android kitkat binary itself (built with whole binary) under `system/priv-app/FileSample.apk`

I am getting the below exception in some rare case. But could not reproduce it again.

I am not using proguard also. I checked all the related issues from StackOverflow, but none of them were related to this kind of system app issue.

So kindly some one help me to find out the root cause for this FATAL Exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.file.SearchProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.file.SearchProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/FileSample.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5115)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4707)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4590)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.file.SearchProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/FileSample.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5100)
01-04 03:16:03.005  8340  8340 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.file.SearchProvider"  may be you have forgot to add this class in Manifest.xml .. Add this class to manifest your problem will be solved.

Comment: Hi @Nepster, The class is added already in Manifest file and that is the basic thing. But the cause is different it seems.

Comment: @Robert do you found the cause of this error any solution?Facing similar issues..??Please Help...

Answer (score 0):

Your class path is not correct!
 For example:
  be cautious of add class(name)!
Hope my answer will help you,thank you!